# syntax error with insert statement

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I am using c/c++ with sqlite.
My code shown below compiles but after I entered my password, I encountered this error.

```
    SQL error: near "NSERT": syntax error
```

I am unable to identify where exactly the syntax error is.

code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


void insertIntoTable(std::string userName,std::string password);

int main () {
    std::string userName;
    std::string password;
    std::cout << "Enter a user name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> userName;
    std::cout << "Enter a password" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> password
    insertIntoTable(userName,password);
} 

//method to insert into table
void insertIntoTable(std::string userName,std::string password) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int  rc;
    const char *sql;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;

    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    if( rc )
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       exit(0);
    }else
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }
   //query
   sql = "INSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) "  \
         "VALUES ("+i,userName,password,j+");"; 
}
```

Please help. thanks

Comment: In the expression, `sql = "INSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) "  \
         "VALUES ("+i,userName,password,j+");";`, the comma-operator makes it like `sql = "INSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) "  \
         "VALUES ("+i;` /* plus other junk that is effectively ignored (as the expressions are evaluated but discarded) */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these answers are terribly wrong. String interpolation for SQL query execution is the express train into injection land. There is no reason why you should ever use it.

The correct way is to use `sqlite3_bind` to bind values against placeholders in the prepared statement, i.e. the code should look like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) "
      "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, nullptr);
// handle rc
// Now bind the parameters.
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, i);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, userName.c_str(), userName.size(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, password.c_str(), password.size(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, j);
// Now execute.
```

Comment: i will try it out.Now

Answer (score 4):

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) "  \
      "VALUES ("+i,userName,password,j+");";
```

That is nonsense. You can't build strings by adding non-string values to a C-style character array or pointer; and the comma operator doesn't append a comma to the string, but instead discards the value of the previous expression after performing its side effects. This means that the whole expression is equivalent to

```
sql = "INSERT..." + i;
```

which adds the value of `i` (1) to the address of a string literal to get a pointer to the second character; so the overall result is `NSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) VALUES (`

You want to use `std::string`. In C++11, there are handy functions to convert numbers to strings:

```
std::string sql = "INSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) "
                  "VALUES (" + std::to_string(i) + ',' 
                             + userName + ','
                             + password + ',' 
                             + std::to_string(j) + ");";
```

Historically, you would need a string-stream

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "INSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) VALUES ("
  << i << ',' << userName << ',' << password << ',' << j << ");";
std::string sql = s.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you a problem with VALUES statement:

```
VALUES ("+i,userName,password,j+");";
```

should be

```
"VALUES ("+std::to_string(i)+","+userName+","+password+","+std::to_string(j)+");";
```

If you don't have std::to_string (no C++11) you need some other way to convert int to std::string, like stringstream.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 80% sure this is how its supposed to be... not sure because its not pure SQL but.. yep

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `Login` (`_id`, `username`, `password`, `manager_id`) "  \
     "VALUES ("+i+", '"+userName+"', '"+password+"', "+j+");";
```

Comment: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [4]’ to binary ‘operator+’

Answer (score 1):

You can not build strings like this..

You have two options.. use `std::string` and form a `string` using `+ operator`. Or if you would like to pursue with `char*` then use code below

```
char *sql = malloc (NumberOfCharYouNeed); //allocate sufficient chars for your purpose.

sprintf (sql, "INSERT INTO Login (_id,username,password,manager_id) VALUES (\"+%d%s%s%d+\")",i,userName,password,j);
```

Note: Make sure you free(sql) after your use.